# jQuery - How to retrieve input values when Typing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, input, keyup

When a user fills out my form, I would like to create a special code.

The code would be the first two letters of each input (input#one, input#two, input#three).

While typing, the "code" would be stored in a variable and set as a value for input#four.

This is my HTML:

```
<form id="gravity">
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="one"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="two" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="email" id="three" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Code:</lable>
        <input type="text" id="four" />
    </li>

</form>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(function() {

 $( "input#one" ).keyup(function() {
    var el1 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
}).keyup();

 $( "input#two" ).keyup(function() {
    var el2 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
}).keyup();

 $( "input#three" ).keyup(function() {
    var el3 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
}).keyup();

var el4 = el1 + el2 + el3;
$("input#four").attr('value', el4);


});
```

So if a user were to enter first name (input#one): `William`, last name (input#two):  `Tell` and Email (input#three):  `williamtell@gmail.com` ->  the code would be:  `witewi`

Where am I going wrong with my jQuery?

Your input is much appreciated!  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/William3780/dmy6o1wm/1/)

Comment: Maybe like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/dmy6o1wm/3/)

Comment: id's are supposed to be unique,don't use tag along with id in the selector , just the id is enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `var` the variable only exists in the container it is declared, so `el1` etc will cease to exist after the function is finished.

Also, this bit of code is only ever run after the page has loaded...

```
var el4 = el1 + el2 + el3;
$("input#four").attr('value', el4);
```

What you need to do is rebuild it each time by putting it in a function and calling the function...

```js
$(function() {
  var el1 = "", el2 = "", el3 = "";

  $( "input#one" ).keyup(function() {
    el1 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
    buildel4();
  });
 
  $( "input#two" ).keyup(function() {
    el2 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
    buildel4();
  });

  $( "input#three" ).keyup(function() {
    el3 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
    buildel4();
  });
  
  function buildel4() {
    var el4 = el1 + el2 + el3;
    $("input#four").attr('value', el4);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="gravity">
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="one"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="text" id="two" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="email" id="three" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Code:</lable>
        <input type="text" id="four" />
    </li>

</form>
```

Here is a [Live Demo using jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9sjpmx9/)

(Also, you don't need the 2nd call to `.keyup();` on each one)

Comment: I don't suppose there is any point asking the downvoter why?  At least when I downvote I have the decency to tell the person why... but you appear to be a coward - hey ho, the joys of the internet

Answer (score 1):

You define local variables `el1`, `el2`, `el3`, that is not accessible from outer context

Try to define it earlier, something like this:

```
$(function() {
   var el1, el2, el3;
   $( "input#one" ).keyup(function() {
      el1 = $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
      var el4 = el1 + el2 + el3;
   $("input#four").attr('value', el4);
}).keyup();
```

Also to automatically update code input you must assign value to it in event handler

https://jsfiddle.net/dmy6o1wm/2/

Answer (score 0):

you are calling $(function(){}). this function will be executed once and will add event listener to your input (first three) elements. and initially they don't have any value. so you are getting null. so call some function to console the final el4 value.

Answer (score 0):

```
instead of using local variable use as global and call the concatenate el4 value on keypress of input like this $("input").keypress
```

`$(function() {
    var flag_1 = false, el1 = "", el2 = "", el3 = "", el4 = "";
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        el1 = $( "input#one" ).val();
        el2 = $( "input#two" ).val();
        el3 =  $( "input#three" ).val();        
       var el4 = el1 + el2 + el3;
        $("input#four").attr('value', el4);
    })

});`


https://jsfiddle.net/rajen_ranjith/dmy6o1wm/9/

Answer (score -2):

You can get this more easily and dynamically on submit the form, like as follow

```js
$(function() {
    $("#click").click(function() {
        var e1 = '';
        $('input[type="text"],input[type="email"]').each(function(){
            //console.log($( this ).val().substr(0,2));
            e1 += $( this ).val().substr(0,2);
        });
        $('#four').val(e1);                   
    });                  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form id="gravity">
    <li>
       One <input type="text" id="one"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        Two<input type="text" id="two" />
    </li>
    <li>
        Three<input type="email" id="three" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Code:</lable>
        <input type="text" id="four" />
    </li>
    <li><button id="click">click</button></li>
</form>
```

Comment: `How to retrieve input values when Typing?`
Will your code run while user is typing ?

Comment: keyup jquery called when you type one character.. up to nth number of times, and it will not give you the proper result so try on form submission and it keep the performance compare to keyup jquery event.... Good Luck...

Comment: `proper result`?
Can you please explain ?

Comment: Using my code,
(1)performance
(2)better result in keyup event it call each function when you type character so just think  I type  NICK in first textbox what it will return. May be : NNINIC... etc.
(3)Dynamically take text from each and every textbox or emailbox  insead of static way. You can now add n number of text box you  not required to edit jquery code now that's the dynamic and reusability.

Comment: `May be` have no value in programming !
Your answer is not working as asked by Op..

Comment: Yes, you are correct, your answer **does** have better performance... but it is **not** what the OP asked for... for multiple reasons